# Creating HTML tags using batch

Tags: html, batch-file, tags

I am trying to read all the HTML file names inside a folder and then trying to write it in another file as a HTML tag attribute value.

Eg. If my file name is `ABC.html` i want to write `<link rel="import" href="ac\abc.html">` inside a new html file, where `ac` will always remain same.

Now the problem is closing tag `>` of an HTML. As it is an expression in batch i end up enclosing my `link` tag inside double quotes. These double quotes are the real problem that i am not able to remove using batch coding. I've tried using `DelayedExpansion` also.

Is there some other way to write HTML tags? or some way through which i can remove these double quotes before writing it into my HTML file?

Comment: Could you provide your solution so i could further see the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is only with `>` character being recognized as a meta-character then you can escape it with `^` like:

```
echo ^<?html^>
```

You can escape any character using this method except for `%` which can only be escaped with double an additional `%` (eg. `%%`)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did tried `^` but i was enclosing `>` on both sides with `^` something that we do while using `"` as `deliminator`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b ^| findstr /i .html') do echo ^<link rel="import"href="ac\%%f"^> >>file.html
```